# git on windows 7 expecting dev null not found error

Tags: windows, git, bash, github, version-control

I'm using Git gui or Git bash on Windows 7 SE 64bit, and I keep getting a weird error. It was working fine before; I haven't made any changes or installed/uninstalled anything. I have already reinstalled and restarted my computer but I'm still getting the same error.

Here goes: after a soft restart, I get

```
Cannot determine Git version:

fatal: open/dev/null or dup failed: No such file or directory

Git gui requires Git 1.5.0 or later"
```

Here is a screenshot of the error window that pops up:

[image]

Any help?

Comment: Can you run `ls /dev/null` from the git bash prompt? (Or can you not get that far?) What version of the git stuff do you have installed? Have you tried reinstalling the git stuff (you said you "reinstalled" but didn't specify what)?

Comment: Are you using the windows version?

Comment: @EtanReisner When enter ls /dev/null in git bash prompt it says...dev/null. I have installed the Git-1.9.4-preview20140815 version and downloaded from this URL: link for Windows.

Comment: @AnubianNoob Yes I'm using windows version.

Comment: Consider my response to [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28941304/getting-errors-when-using-github-for-windows/34307471#34307471).

Comment: @EtanReisner can you share the URL here again, please.

Comment: @AnubianNoob yes, I am using windows 10, upgraded from windows 7 but was having the same issue on windows 7 as well.

Comment: @Bioukh That worked for me - or so I thought.  The problem came back after one or more hibernates and/or restarts.

Comment: @WindowsEscapist : [This](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/9b5cd375-ed22-4e31-baf8-f714a3d60303/null-device-does-not-start?forum=w7itproinstall) may help you understanding why null device fails.

Comment: @Bioukh I did take a look at that earlier, but found that I didn't have Away Mode enabled in my current power state.  I checked my null.sys against one from some random DLL download site, and the checksums didn't match - so either they're full of crap (likely) or I've just got filesystem corruption.  I'm running `DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth` at the moment, which is supposed to check system file integrity and download new copies from Windows Update if necessary.

Comment: `DISM` gave me an error message and 90K lines of logfile, but nothing promising.  Don't think my troubles will be relevant to this question (or resolved anytime soon).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, installing Git using the parameters by default, it should create the folder structure `/dev/null` in `C:\program files\.git` Like `C:\program files\git\dev\null`.

I have installed Git 2.7.0.2 64-bit in a VM machine with Windows 10 64-bit. It created these folders `/dev/null` and in another machine with the same OS it doesn't create those folders, even using the same installer.

Creating this folder manually, the message disappear.

No idea why it doesn't create, even whether antivirus or windows defender are disabled.

Comment: I have installed git on windows 7 but I couldn't locate this directory C:\program files\git\dev\null and its running fine without these folders.